# Ruby global variable alternative

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I know global variables should never be used but right now it's the only thing that I can get to work. So I'm looking for alternatives. What I want to do is pass `@array` which is is in method `two` in class `New`, to method `one`. The only way I was able to accomplish this is with `$array`.

```
module Test::Abc
  class << self
    def one
      ....
    end

    class New
      def two
        @array=[]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's what I did to get the result I needed...

```
module Test::Abc
  class << self
    def one(array)
      ....
    end
  end

  class New
    def two
      @array=[]
      array=@array
      Test::Abc::one(array)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: An instance variable `@array` is specific to a particular instance of `Test::Abc::New`. Unless you specify within `one` which instance of `Test::Abc::New` you are looking at, you will not be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks sawa for the reply... you've described exactly what I'm not able to do! :) I have no idea how to specify from one the @array.

Comment: If the only way you can accomplish something is with a global variable, you should very strongly consider redesigning your code entirely. For example, why not just use a method parameter? Further, are you certain you want to define the `New` class within the singleton of `Test::Abc`?

Comment: @Andrew thank you for your suggestions. Even though I've been playing with ruby for awhile I'm no programmer, obviously ;) But I looked into method parameters and moving the **New** class out side the singleton of **Test::ABC** and after some trial and error I was able to get it to work!

Comment: @FrankN If you've solved your problem, you should either post your answer below, which you can accept after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely.

Comment: @Andrew, I'll definitively post my solution once I figure it out... but seems I spoke too soon. I'm able to access ***@array*** from outside the ***New*** class but when I then try access it from the ***one*** method the program goes into an endless loop. Later tonight I'll keep messing with it and report back my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with as a solution...

```
module Test::Abc
  class << self
    def one(array)
      ....
    end
  end

  class New
    def two
      @array=[]
      array=@array
      Test::Abc::one(array)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with your answer, this should also work (slight modification):

```
module Test::Abc
  class << self
    def one(array)
      ....
    end
  end

  class New
    def two
      @array=[]
      Test::Abc::one(@array)
    end
  end
end
```